# Can you create a remote directory using sshPut command in Jenkings

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I'm trying to use sshPut commands to put files into a remote directory. The issue is that the directory doesn't exist. Can sshPut be used to simply create a remote directory? This is what my steps look like now:

```
sshPut failOnError: true, remote: dev_repo, from: './MyProgram.exe', into: "/home/releases/${env.MYPROG_VERSION}/"
sshPut failOnError: true, remote: dev_repo, from: './MyProgram.pdb', into: "/home/releases/${env.MYPROGAM_VERSION}/"
sshPut failOnError: true, remote: dev_repo, from: './ThirdParty.dll', into: "/home/releases/${env.MYPROGAM_VERSION}/"
```

where env.MYPROGRAM_VERSION is set earlier in the Jenkinsfile.

The issue is that the directory does not exist, and I want to create it. I don't have a directory with that name on the build machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one step before the `sshPut`: a [`sshCommand`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/)

```
sshCommand remote: remote, command: "mkdir -p "/home/releases/${env.MYPROGAM_VERSION}"
```

That way, the folder is created first, then `sshPut` can operate successfully.

Comment: I guess that would work, but it's specific to a linux machine being the SFTP server.

Comment: You could translate this into a Windows mkdir command, no?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather that it was server agnostic. sshPut should be able to create a directory on the destination without there having to be a local directory, or sshPut should have a flag to create any needed directories.